# pex packaging a simple script file

Tags: python, virtualenv, pants

I created a simple python script file called main.py which requires some dependency libraries.
I pip installed freezed them into a requirements.txt (in a virtualenv) and now I want to package them both to make a single executable that just runs the script

what's the right way to generate it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To generate a `out.pex` file from your `main.py` script and `requirements.txt` file, you can utilize the following command:

```
pex -r requirements.txt --exe main.py -o out.pex
```

It's important to note that the resulting `pex` file will include your code and its dependencies, but it will not include the Python interpreter. Hence, it is necessary to ensure that the target machine has the appropriate Python interpreter installed.

When you generate the `out.pex` file using `pex 2.1.137`, the resulting file structure will typically resemble the following:

```
.bootstrap/
.deps/  <-- Dependencies will be stored in this directory.
__pex__/
__main__.py  <-- This is the actual entry-point that uses a shebang (hash sign) and wraps your main.py script.
__pex_executable__.py  <-- Your main.py script will be located here.
PEX-INFO
```